# How to use Vue to show data in distinct divs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So, I really need to use Vue for a project. But I'm confused on how to go about this.

Basically, I have a card:

```
<div id="card"></div>
```

I'm populating various data into each card from the backend. So, basically, if I have 10 distinct items, I will have 10 different cards that look like this:

```
<div id="card"></div>
<div id="card"></div>
<div id="card"></div>
<div id="card"></div>
<div id="card"></div>
<div id="card"></div>
<div id="card"></div>
```

But I want to be able to use Vue to manipulate each card differently (for example, I need to show different charts on different cards). How do I go about this?

(I thought about using multiple vue instances, but that won't work because all divs have "card" as an id)

Comment: You could create card component that will accept certain props - based on your needs.Then loop over the data from backend and for each item render card component and pass data down over the prop.That's how things in theory should work, but question is a bit vague and abstract.

Comment: You are populating HTML into the cards, and then want to control them with Vue?

Comment: Also don't have multiple `id` attributes with the same name